# About reserved domains name

Tags: domain, wiki, domain-name, tld

According to this wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain#Reserved_domains)

Followings are reserved domains:

```
example: reserved for use in examples
invalid: reserved for use in obviously invalid domain names
localhost: reserved to avoid conflict with the traditional use of localhost 
           as a hostname
test: reserved for use in tests
```

However I can see that someone is using invalid.com and test.com. So is that wiki is incorrect or rules are changed in INTERNET world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Top level domain names are things like ".com", ".org", ".net." and country codes.

The reserved ones you list are for ".invalid" not "invalid.com". The Wikipedia article links to more info for each one:

- [.example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.example)
- [.localhost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.localhost)
- [.invalid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.invalid)
- [.test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.test)